# ionic cordova run android --prod won't allow custom calendar

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to run my app in prod mode, however I keep getting the following errors:

> 1. If 'calendar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

I've already tried importing the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` and `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` into my NgModule decorator in my module file, but I still keep getting the same.

Ionic Info:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.1
    @ionic/cli-utils        : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI             : 6.0.0
    Ionic CLI               : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 5.1.1, browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1

System:

    Node       : v6.10.0
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

Comment: What is `Calendar`? A custom component? a Page?

Comment: A custom component, yes. This specifically https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar#note-for-ionic-buildrun-command)?

Comment: Did you add the Calendar component to the imports array in app.module.ts? Or if you use other NgModules to the imports array of this module?

Comment: @sebaferreras yes but I'm confused about the file he is referencing. where is main.prod.ts in an ionic app?

Comment: @David I imported the calendar component in app.module.ts